# How do I get one column from multiple tables to join into one list?

Tags: c#, sql, list, lambda, distinct

I need a list of Names from multiple tables. `Table A`, `Table B`, `Table C`, `Table D`. 
Table A,B & C have one column "`CompanyName`" which I need to be put in a list together with table D's column "`ConsumerName`". As I only need one column of distinct values from all the tables, is it possible to add all of these tables together without using a join? This is to be used for comparison with a user input. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an UNION instead of a join

```
SELECT CompanyName from A
UNION
SELECT CompanyName from B
UNION
SELECT CompanyName from C
UNION
SELECT ConsumerName from D
```

The result of a UNION is always distinct, th version with duplicates is UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

Posted a suggestion in the comments, but I didn't take into account your 'Distinct' condition, and it makes the code slightly longer, so I'll post an answer.

A reference to **System.Linq** is needed, and I'm assuming you have the values of the 4 tables stored.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();

values.AddRange(tableA.Select(ta => ta.CompanyName).ToList());

var tableBVals = tableB.Where(tb => !values.Contains(tb.CompanyName)).ToList();
values.AddRange(tableBVals);

var tableCVals = tableC.Where(tc => !values.Contains(tc.CompanyName)).ToList();
values.AddRange(tableCVals);

var tableDVals = tableD.Where(td => !values.Contains(td.ConsumerName)).ToList();
values.AddRange(tableDVals);
```

I realize its longer and messier than you want, but it will do in a pinch.